# npm install is partially cloning the source from git repo

Tags: node.js, git, npm, bitbucket, npm-install

When I run `npm i` command it partially clones the code from bitbucket repo. Here are some dependencies in `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
   "bluerain-app-hello-world": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/projects/bluerain-app-hello-world.git#build_issue",
   "graphql-tag": "0.1.16" }
```

And this is the source of my module
[image]

But when i list down cloned rope from node_module by

```
ls node_modules/bluerain-app-hello-world/
```

It gives this list

```
index.js  node_modules  package.json  README.md  src
```

There is a **dist** folder in my source but it didnt  clone properly. I tried to remove my node modules and reinstall it but it didnt work. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I suspect this is your .gitignore.

Comment: `*.idea

logs

*.log

npm-debug.log*

build/Release

node_modules
.npm
.eslintcache
.node_repl_history
*.tgz
.idea
`
.gitignore

Comment: Couldn't be ignore rules; ignore rules *only* affect listing of untracked files

Comment: Are there any files actually in `dist`?  Just a random thought, but git doesn't cooperate well with empty directories...

Comment: There are 3 folders and 9 files and in dist folder :(

Answer (score 3):

I started working on a boilerplate who had added the **files** array field in package.json and specified only the `src` folder. This is why when my node module installed, it didn't contain the `dist` folder.

[According to official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files)

The "files" field is an array of files to include in your project. If you name a folder in the array, then it will also include the files inside that folder. (Unless they would be ignored by another rule.)

You can also provide a ".npmignore" file in the root of your package or in subdirectories, which will keep files from being included, even if they would be picked up by the files array. The .npmignore file works just like a .gitignore.

Comment: This is especially important for forked repos. Usually the original repo creators add a bunch of stuff in the npmignore file that makes `npm install` from the git url download an incomplete package.